# pdblp: bulkref start date override

Tags: bloomberg, pdblp

I'm trying to query release dates for a ticker using pdblp. This is my attempt:

```
with pdblp.bopen() as c:
    c.bulkref('AUM3 Index', 'ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST')
```

But the results I'm getting are between Jan 2019 and Dec 2020. How can I get information about release dates further back? I've tried to override the start date but none of the attempts succeeded:

`ovrds=[('start_dt', '20000101')]`
`ovrds=[('start_date', '20000101')]`
`ovrds=[('START_DATE', '20000101')]`

I've also tried:
`c.bdh('AUM3 Index', 'ECO_RELEASE_DT', '20000101', '20200609')`

But this one generates no results at all.

The live Bloomberg help doesn't support Python API.

Comment: Can you get it working in Excel?

Comment: @assylias yes using `=BDS` but it doesn't exist in `pdblp` and the override uses `START_DT` which also doesn't work with what I've tried.

Comment: It's easier to answer your question if you give all the information (like the full Excel formula and the full python code). I'll put an answer based on what I have guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bds is:

```
=BDS("AUM3 Index", "ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST", "START_DATE=20000101")
```

You could try something like this:

```
c.ref(["AUM3 Index"], "ECO_RELEASE_DT_LIST", [("START_DATE","20000101"),])
```

Reference: https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp/issues/25

Comment: Doesn't work.. It ignores the override and returns just the next release which is this month.

Comment: And yes that's the Excel formula I've tried (maybe `START_DT` instead of `START_DATE`). @assylias